# Want to implement Play, Pause and Resume mp3 using MediaObject, actions-on-google npm lib

Tags: actions-on-google

Currently i have a use case to Play, Pause and Resume a large mp3 file. As per google assistant document there is no way to pause and resume the audio player using MediaObject through actions-on-google npm lib.

Has anyone achieved success on this ???. any assistant would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The current Media Response gives the user the ability to pause and resume the Media control, but doesn't give any feedback to you when that happens, nor does it give you any way to preempt a playing media.